# return or not return

Tags: lua

I'm learning Lua coroutines. I found a weired thing to me, both

```
meta = function ()
    for i = 1, 10 do
        coroutine.yield(i)
    end
end

for i in coroutine.wrap(function() return meta() end) do
    print(i)
end
```

and

```
meta = function ()
    for i = 1, 10 do
        coroutine.yield(i)
    end
end

for i in coroutine.wrap(function() meta() end) do
    print(i)
end
```

(note there is return in the first version)give me

```
~/test% lua t.lua
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

So, what is the role of `return`? I think `meta()` will return a value and the anonymous function should return it as well. So why the anonymous function without `return` is also right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `meta` does not return anything - at least nothing important.

The output passed to the `i` variable of the outer loop comes from the `yield` method, not from the return.

You can see this if you write the loop like this:

```
for i in coroutine.wrap(function()
           val = {meta()}
           print ("----")
           print (val)
        end) do
    print(i)
end
```

The output is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
----
nil
```

The anoymous function, as well as `meta`, is called only once.

Comment: Thanks! So I know coroutine.resume/yield is an other path of "returning" values. ;)